# How does kubectl being authorized?

Tags: kubernetes

I have been confused for a long time about how the user of kubectl being authorized. I bootstrap a k8s cluster from scratch and use 'RBAC' as the authorization mode. The user kubectl used is authenticated by certificate first, then it should be authorized by RBAC when accessing the api-server. I did nothing about granting permissions to the user, however, it is allowed to access all the apis(creating pod or listing pods).

Comment: Can you describe how you're setting up kubectl? For eg: are you running kubectl on the VM directly, or are you on GEK and running it from your machine and configuring it via `gcloud containers`?

Comment: @iamnat I installed k8s on bare metal from scratch according to this document: https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/scratch/

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes has no built in user management system. It expects you to implement that part on your own. In this sense, a common way to implement user auth is to create a certificate sign request and have it signed by the cluster certificate authority. By reading that newly generated certificate, the cluster will extract the username and the groups it belongs to. Then, after that, it will apply the RBAC policies you implemented. In this sense, if the user can access everything, then it can be one of the following:

- You are still using the admin user account instead of the newly created user account.
- The user account you created belongs to an admin group
- You did not enable RBAC correctly

This guide should help you with an easy example of user auth in Kubernetes: https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/